# Unable to select data from MySql database using Php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble selecting data from a MySql database which I have created in phpMyAdmin. The output is always: "invalid username" even though I have inserted the data I want to select from the database named `st_login` and the table named `login` in phpMyAdmin. Can someone show me the error?

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
print ("<form action='logincontroltest.php' method='post'>

    <p>Username
        <input type='text' name='username' />
    </p>
    <p>Password
        <input type='password' name='password' >
        <p/>
    <input type='submit' value='Log In'/>
</form>");
extract ($_POST);
if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
    print("Could not connect");
if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password']) )
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    if ( !empty($username) &&!empty($password) ) 
    {
        $query = " SELECT 'id' FROM login WHERE   'username'='$username' AND 'password'='$password'  ";
        if($result=mysql_query($query,$database))
        {
            $query_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($query_num_rows==0){
                echo "invalid username";}
            else if($query_num_rows==1) {
                echo "You logged in successfully";
            }
        } 
        die (mysql_error());
    }
    else echo "Fill in all blank fields";
} 
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: A concrete response please!

Comment: That is a concrete response. If you're going to want to code, you also need to do what goes with the territory, and that is called "debug". If you're just doing this for kicks, then have fun.

Comment: I'd of closed your question with that ^ I voted too soon.

Comment: `SELECT 'id'` you don't encapsulate the table names with `quotes`, you use backticks **`**, but in your case, `id` isn't reserved, so you can just use `id`.

Comment: 'id' is a field table not a table name

Comment: You've been given an answer below. A wrong one, but an answer nonetheless. Oh, sure it'll work; if your data are integers, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Here are 2 terms you also need to learn. 1) **String Literals** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html 2) **Identifier Qualifiers** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html - That's if you're serious about coding (MySQL). If not, then just disregard it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @-Fred -ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about error reporting - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

And, doesnt the single quotes in SQL query breaks it? Try to use this:

```
$query = " SELECT id FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' "
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helped me even though the correct answer is:          $query = " SELECT `id` FROM `login` WHERE   `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'  ";

Comment: @EldaBacka You're sending the wrong message here by accepting that answer in its present state. This tells the community and visitors to the answer that using it like that, is proper syntax, which isn't.

Comment: This is why i wrote the right answer in the comment.It was approximately a right answer

Comment: @EldaBacka Still; wrong message. This person needs to edit their answer accordingly. A comment is a comment. An answer is supposed to provide an actual "solution".

Comment: Done, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @EldaBacka if you're talking to me, I don't spoonfeed people, I teach them to learn and you haven't learned anything as to why your code failed in the first place. Edit: You deleted your comment about theirs being a better answer than mine; probably the links I gave you to "learn" proper syntax.

Comment: Sorry @-Fred -ii- when your time is limited a concrete demonstration of the errors really helps better than a php manual